# Replace Hover Trigger with onClick on Woodmart Theme Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am setting up a shop with [this woodmart theme](https://woodmart.xtemos.com/mega-electronics/blog/) and it has this "Sticky Navigation" element (Blue circle burger icon All Categories). It can be placed in a menu in the header, as well as vertical on the left side of the page. They appear to be have very similar code, just used in two places. However, the instance in the header menu has options to change the icon and action behavior - specifically, the click or hover to open. The one on the left however, it does not share those settings for some odd reason.

I have been trying for quite a while to change this through either the "Custom CSS" or "Custom JS" field in the theme settings. However, I haven't been able to get that working. I tried looking through the CSS by using the browser inspector, and am not seeing any `:hover` that changes size. My assumption is that it is done with newer-ish CSS methods that I'm not fluent with... but I am pretty rusty on the web dev space so the solution is not standing out for me.

I tried to copy the CSS classes from the header menu instance to the left side menu with jQuery in an attempt to use the built in code for the action handling, but it did not work - and actually just made the other menu stop working.

The basic jQuery I tried was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.wd-sticky-nav-title').addClass('wd-tools-element wd-header-sticky-nav wd-style-icon wd-design-1 wd-close-menu-mouseout whb-5g5aiuasdasdakjdksad');
})
```

I think the hover effect is terrible, and should be opened on click instead - and ideally - close on mouse out. If anyone easily sees a solution, I sure would appreciate a tip on how to achieve the change.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The hover that changes the size is the following line : `.wd-sticky-nav:is(:hover,.wd-opened){
    width: 275px;
}`

Comment: but then there is some js that needs changing as well.

Comment: For the JS part, it should probably be enough if you add a click handler to `.wd-sticky-nav-title`, that _triggers_ a click event on the button in the header menu.